# How can I restructure my database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a collection with embedded documents. This worked fine when updating a document within a document, but when I had to update a document within a document within a document problems arose. To make this work I would need to use a double '$' and this is not possible. 
This works:

```
{$push: {
        "progress.$.exercise":{
            "exercise":exercise
        }
}
```

This is where the problem comes in:

```
{$push: {
        "progress.$.exercise.$.workout":{
            "_set":_set, 
            "reps":reps,
            "weight":weight
        }
    }
```

Since dobbel $ can't be done and there seems to be no way (that I can find) to do it with elemMatch. I can only come to the conclusion that the way I have structured my Database is wrong....

Here are my Schemas:

```
var Workout = new mongoose.Schema({
    _set : {
        type: String
    },
    reps: {
        type: String
    },
    weight: {
        type: String
    }
});


var Exercise = new mongoose.Schema({
    exerciseName : {
        type: String
    },
    workout : [Workout]
});


var Progress = new mongoose.Schema({
    date : {
        type: String
    },
    name : {
        type: String
    },
    exercise : [Exercise]
});


var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    progress : [Progress]

});


var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

It seems I need to restructure my database, if so how should I do this? 
Do I need to make more collections? 
I'm used to relational databases and if I where to make collections out of all of them it would start to look like that.

Comment: First thing you should look at is embedded document vs reference. This will give you a way..